# how many rectangles in a circle with defined measurements

Tags: multivariable-calculus, circles, rectangles

[example of rectangles in circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coWgi.png)

i have various size plates as follows
12m
10m
8m
6m
4m

i need to be able to calculate how many rectangles i need in a quardrant(can be mirrored for other quadrants)
the restraints are as follows
all rectangles on the edge can have no less than 500mm horizontally from the edge of the circle
where a rectangle finishes it must be at least 300mm from the rectangle above or below where that one finishes (we usually stick them in the middle for ease)
the larger the rectangle the better but does not all need to be the same size whatever uses the least amount of rectangles the better.
rectangles that hit the edge of the circle can be less than 4m all other plates must be bigger

is there a way to mathematically calculate how to do this at the moment we just do alot of trial and error but can be time consuming

Comment: According to [Erich's Packing Center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/), the best way to pack squares in a circle isn't known even for 3 squares. That said, a relevant expert/algorithms person may know a good way to code a search for a pretty-good solution to your rectangle problem.

Comment: Your run-on sentences, complete lack of punctuation, and very incomplete descriptions make it next to impossible to figure out what you are describing. Can you please, please, please rewrite it as if speaking to someone who doesn't live inside your head, or already know what you are talking about.